# Does the Ward keyword trigger Baral's card draw clause?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Ward, the new keyword introduced in Strixhaven, counters spells and abilities that target that creature unless you pay a cost.

> Ward {2} (Whenever this creature becomes the target of a spell or ability an opponent controls, counter it unless that player pays {2}.)

[image: The card Waterfall Aerialist. A 3 power 1 toughness Djinn Wizard for 3 generic and 1 blue mana. It has flying and Ward 2.]

Now, [Baral, Chief of Compliance](https://scryfall.com/card/aer/28/baral-chief-of-compliance) says this:

> Whenever a spell or ability you control counters a spell, you may draw a card. If you do, discard a card.

Does the Ward keyword count as an ability for the purposes of Baral's draw ability?

Comment: If I saw this card without context, here's how I would analyze it: this word is unfamiliar, so it must be an ability word, keyword action, or keyword ability. It's not an ability word, because it's not italics, and it's not a keyword action, because those always appear within the text of other abilities. Therefore, it must be a keyword ability, and those are all abilities by definition. The reminder text starts with the word "Whenever", which makes it specifically a triggered ability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is confirmed by the [Strixhaven mechanics guide](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/strixhaven-school-mages-mechanics-2021-03-25):

> Ward is a triggered ability.

More generally, a triggered ability is defined as (Comprehensive Rules 603.1):

> Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

The reminder text for Ward meets that pattern; while reminder text formally has no bearing on the game, it is intended to be helpful and it would be very *unhelpful* for the reminder text to meet the pattern of a triggered ability without being one.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Ward will only trigger effects triggered by spells being countered if the opponent chooses not to pay the Ward cost.